# How to run FragmentBasics sample in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, fragment

I'm new to Android development. I am following the tutorial to the Fragment section. I downloaded the FragmentBasics.zip and unzipped it to my drive. In Android Studio 3.0, I imported it as a project but I found under "Android", there is no "App" which I could try to run it. Can someone show me how to try this example please?

Thanks

Comment: check this https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/creating-project.html

Comment: Can you provide link, from where you downloaded the framentBasics.zip

Comment: @rajahsekar I downloaded the FragementBasics.zip and it contails all project info, not creating a new Project. Hence my question is how to make that downloaded project working?

Comment: @MuhammadHannan It's part of Android Studio training. https://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/index.html